# Extjs Grid. Binding record's property to cell's disabled property

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to do such a thing? I know that it's possible with `widgetcolumn`, but I can't find such a possibility for normal column. Let's say I have model like that and it's shown in grid:

```
{name: 'active', type: 'boolean'},
{name: 'text', type: 'string'}
```

and in grid I have column:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{!record.active}'
    },
    listeners: {
        checkchange: 'onChange'
    },
},
```

it would work for widgetColumn, but it doesn't work for checkColumn. Is it a way to make blocking such checkColumn possible without using widget?

Comment: is this for modern or classic ?

Comment: I use classic one (6.2)